# session variables best practice over multiple database queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that pulls 2-3 chunks of data from sql.
these chunks are broken into about 20 different variables.

Each page you navigate to will use the same data over and over.

Question:

should i place all the variables in session variables or should i query the database on each page, re-establishing the data and variables each time.

some of the pages modify the database and subsequently the variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be good to have a caching mechanism. However, php's session variables are not the best solution. You could use a caching system such as APC or MemCached, or you could simply store them into a file on the hard disk.

Reasons not to use session variables:

1. The scope. I bet that some of your variables may have a wider scope than a session. In other words, some of the variables may be shared between different sessions.
2. Eager loading. Every time you call `session_start`, **all** the variables are going to be unserialized and loaded whether you need them or not.

Comment: I am going to look at your two suggestions. Haven't used them yet so i need to study them. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You should store data in `$_SESSION` whenever possible (assuming it's not a large amount of data and it's used always over and over and over).

Your greatest problem than would be what will happen if data changes. You may refresh them from time to time with code such as:

```php
if( rand(0,100) < 10){
   readSessionsFromPost();
}
```

The another way is to modify local file and check it in every request via `mtime` (and store last value in `$_SESSION`). Or you can use:

```php
$time = $db->fetch_one( 'SELECT MAX(mtime) FROM pages');
strtotime( $time) >= $_SESSION['time'];
```

To sum up.

If you don't care that user gets current data 20 requests later, you should go with rand (I actually would care and would never use this :) ).

If you have access to configure file access you should use `mtime` and modified time (no request on database required).

And if you're having just few users and great reserve in server performance you should just load them every time (or when data changes every few seconds).

Cache adds some overhead and you must decide whether caching those data is performance critical.